# Log4net - adding LogicalThreadContext to every request in .NET WebAPI project

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to add a `LogicalThreadContext` to every request in my `WebAPI` project.

I have added the following code to my `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["context"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    }
```

But for some reason its not working(even if the thread id did not change).

I also tried adding an `ActionFilter` in the controller level which works fine but I prefer a global life-cycle action to do it once

Answer (score 0):

I just created a ASP.NET-application and added this to global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ipAddress"] = ipAddress;
        log.Info("Application_BeginRequest");
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        log.Info("Application_EndRequest");
}
```

In the config for log4net I added `%property{ipAddress}` to print 
the IP-adress of the user to the logfile. The config for my appender is:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\example.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{ipAddress} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

And this what I can see in c:\temp\example.log, 
if I browse to a page of my web application:

```
::1 - Application_BeginRequest
::1 - Application_EndRequest
```

The only reason I can think of why it is not working in your case is this sentence I found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.LogicalThreadContext.html):

> The Logical Thread Context is managed on a per CallContext basis. 
>   The CallContext requires a link time SecurityPermission for the 
>   Infrastructure. If the calling code does not have this permission 
>   then this context will be disabled. It will not store any property values set > on it.

This means, that if you don't have `link time SecurityPermission`, then your code
is working. Try changing LogicalThreadContext to ThreadContext and see if it makes a difference.